# How to use lapply only for one specific argument of a function?

Tags: r

So I have a function that takes more than one argument and I want to use apply for just values of one of the arguments.
I'll use an example:

```
v<-c("a","b","c","d")

f<-function(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4){
}
```

I tried using this line of code, because I only want to use the "arg2":

```
x<-lapply(v,f(),arg2=arg2)
```

Unfortunately I got the error:

Error in check_args_given_nonempty(args, c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4",  : 
  You must provide a non-empty value to at least one of
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: Is this what you had in mind: `lapply(1:4, function(x) {rnorm(n=10, mean=x, sd=5)})`

Comment: Can you post a more complete and clearer example, ideally with some expected output? I can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: ```fun<-function(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4){}
x<-lapply(v,f(x) fun(arg1, x, arg3,arg4))```

Comment: The output I expect is basically executing the function for each member of the vector "v"... the thing is "v" can only be used in the "arg2" of the functions. I would post the actual function but it's so specific I wouldn't be able to explain myself, sorry I'm being confusing

Comment: Regardless of any other issues, you will definitely need to get rid of the parentheses after `f()` in your call to `lapply`, as in `x <- lapply(v, f)` because including the parentheses means the result of a call to `f()` is being passed as the argument `FUN` to `lapply`, but without the parentheses, the function `f` itself is passed as the argument `FUN`, which is what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Specify the fixed arguments like this:

```
f <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) paste(x1, x2, x3, x4)
lapply(1:5, f, x1 = "a", x3 = "c", x4 = "d")
```

giving

```
[[1]]
[1] "a 1 c d"

[[2]]
[1] "a 2 c d"

[[3]]
[1] "a 3 c d"

[[4]]
[1] "a 4 c d"

[[5]]
[1] "a 5 c d"
```

**2)** or wrap it into a one-argument function:

```
lapply(1:5, function(x) f("a", x, "c", "d"))
```

**3)** There are also a number of packages that will accept a function as input and output a function with some of the arguments fixed, known as currying.  Here are two different packages that can curry a function.

```
library(purrr)
lapply(1:5, partial(f, list(x1 = "a", x3 = "c", x4 = "d")))

library(functional)
lapply(1:5, Curry(f, x1 = "a", x3 = "c", x4 = "d"))
```